# Циклическая ошибка

Tags: python

почему у меня не работает переменная в данном цикле?

```
def logical_concatenetion():
    for part in listParts:
        i = 0
        i += 1
        lifePart = listParts [i]
        print (lifePart)
```

Comment: потому что Вы зануляете переменую каждый раз

Answer (score 0):

А что вы хотите добиться этим кодом?

У вас в цикле постоянно `i = 1` и вы выводите содержимое `listParts[1]`

Что именно вы хотите?

```
for part in listParts:
    print(part)
```

Или

```
for i in range(len(listParts)):
    print(listParts[i])
```